# How to equally align two vertical columns created using a loop, an array, and appending childs in JavaScript (or CSS)?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, for-loop, alignment

What I am trying to do is generate HTML with JavaScript using loops and arrays.  What I am currently trying (and having issue with) is my second column. I have an array of courses to that are placed into input checkboxes followed by labels.  From there I used an if statement to add breaks after every second iteration to create my columns.  My problem is getting the second column to align vertically.  I wanted to do it using just JS and not CSS, but I am open to either.

Since my question has multiple parts, I wasn't sure what keywords to use to use to narrow my search for aligning columns using .createElement in a loop to create 2 columns and align them vertically in JavaScript, so if this has been answered in another place, feel free to drop a line.

Here is the relevent code.

HTML

```
<body>
<section id="wrapper">
<form action="POST" novalidate="novalidate">
<fieldset id="contactInfo">
<legend>Contact Info</legend>
<label>Name: </label>
<input type="text" placeholder="John" required autofocus /><br>
<label>Email: </label>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="galacticDonut@yahoo.com" required /><br>
<label>Age: </label>
<select></select>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="Programs">
<legend>Programs</legend>
<ul></ul>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
//************************
//Generate course options list

function generateCourses() {
    var courseOptions =  ["CSCI","CSIA","DBMS","INFA","ITSP","NETI","SDEV","SVAD"]
    courseOptions.sort();

    var uList = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];

    for (var i=0; i<courseOptions.length; i++) {
    //Create inputs
    var labels = document.createElement("label");
    labels.innerHTML = courseOptions[i];

    var inputs = document.createElement("input");
    inputs.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    //Set input value
        inputs.value = courseOptions[i];
    //Set input text
        inputs.text = courseOptions[i];
    //Put input in UL
        uList.appendChild(inputs);
    //place label in ul after checkboxes
        uList.appendChild(labels)
        if (i % 2) {
            var breakLine = document.createElement("br");
            uList.appendChild(breakLine);
        }//End if
    }//End for loop
} //End generateCourses function
```

Here is the full code
https://jsfiddle.net/gat4vo9p/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code a bit:

https://jsfiddle.net/gat4vo9p/7/

Added an `li` element inside `ul`. Each `li` behaves like a table row.

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

li {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
li > span {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Also added `<label for` attribute. So clicking on the label will mark/unmark the checkbox, as well.